# Why does apache work only with mpm-prefork?

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, wordpress, mpm-worker, mpm-event

I have 2 websites of wordpress on LAMP (Linux, Apache2, MariaDB and PHP-FPM).

If I disable mpm-prefork and enable either mpm-worker or mpm-event, apache shows only a blank page (I have a few wordpress websites).

The weird thing is log says nothing about of problemas.

I have the following configuration of Apache

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.example.com (/etc/httpd24/conf.sh/example-80.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/httpd24/conf.sh/example-80.conf:1)
                 alias example.com
         port 80 namevhost www.sub.example.com (/etc/httpd24/conf.sh/sub-80.conf:1)
                 alias sub.example.com
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ip-172-31-0-20.ec2.internal (/etc/httpd24/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
         port 443 namevhost ip-172-31-0-20.ec2.internal (/etc/httpd24/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
         port 443 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/httpd24/conf.sh/example.conf:1)
                 alias example.com
         port 443 namevhost www.sub.example.com (/etc/httpd24/conf.sh/sub.conf:1)
                 alias sub.example.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd24"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd24/logs/error_log"
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex lua-ivm-shm: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/etc/httpd24/run/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex cache-socache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/etc/httpd24/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

And this are the relevant modules:

```
httpd24 -M | egrep  'proxy|http2|event'
 http2_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_hcheck_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_uwsgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
```

Tha version of packages are:

```
httpd24-httpd-tools-2.4.34-22.el7.x86_64
rh-php73-php-fpm-7.3.20-1.el7.x86_64
httpd24-libnghttp2-1.7.1-8.el7.1.x86_64
httpd24-httpd-2.4.34-22.el7.x86_64
httpd24-mod_ssl-2.4.34-22.el7.x86_64
httpd24-runtime-1.1-19.el7.x86_64
httpd24-1.1-19.el7.x86_64
```

The OS is Centos 7:

```
uname -a ; cat /etc/redhat-release 
Linux ip-172-31-0-20.ec2.internal 3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 18:28:22 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

Why does this occur?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning up your ErrorLog LogLevel to debug.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlog